# Image is not seen in web in Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web, flask

[image: Image is not seen]

I have tried all possibilities, but when I click the button its not showing me image that I took dynamically from the local pc. Is has 3 to 4 app-routes with 3 to 4 different Html.(one was bs.html). In this I have two modules: one for detecting body segmentation and other for brain tumor detection.
app.py

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN1.model")
the_model = torch.load('cnn.pt')


app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True, static_url_path = "/static", static_folder = "static")


UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def prepare(file): #image-processing for body segmentation
    ---------
    ---------
    return sample_array

def transform(file): #image-processing for brain tumor
    ----------
    ----------
    return img_t



@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Main page
    return render_template('RCnn.html')

@app.route('/body_seg')
def body_seg():
    return render_template('bs1.html')


@app.route('/brain_t')
def brain_t():
    return render_template('brain1.html')

@app.route('/body', methods=['POST','GET']) #to detect body segmentation parts
def body():

        if request.method =='POST':
            file1 = request.files['file']
            if file1:
                filename = secure_filename(file1.filename)
                # task 1. let's get a clear path
                path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
                path = os.path.abspath(path)

            # task 2. make sure the folder exists
                folder = os.path.dirname(path)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder):
                    raise IOError('no such folder: %s' % folder)

                file1.save(path)


        abc=prepare(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))

        uploadimage=file1.filename

        prediction = model.predict(abc)
        return render_template('bs1.html',image=uploadimage, data=data2, data3=data3)



@app.route('/brain', methods=['POST','GET']) #module to detect brain tumor
def brain():
    if request.method =='POST':
            file1 = request.files['file']
            if file1:
                filename = secure_filename(file1.filename)
                # task 1. let's get a clear path
                path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
                path = os.path.abspath(path)

            # task 2. make sure the folder exists
                folder = os.path.dirname(path)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder):
                    raise IOError('no such folder: %s' % folder)

                file1.save(path)

    #torch.save(model_conv,'cnn.pt')
    the_model = torch.load('cnn.pt')

    img_t = transform(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
    uploadimage1=file1.filename


    batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)

    out = the_model(batch_t)
    return render_template('brain1.html',image1=uploadimage1,data=data4, data3=data5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

bs.html

```
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor = "#ffeee6">
 <h1><center><u>Radiological Image Classification</u></center></h1>
 <h2><u>Body Part Segment Detection </u></h2>
 <p><bold>Upload your Radiological image with different body parts: </bold></p> 
 <form action = "/body" method ='POST' enctype=multipart/form-data>
 <input type="file" name="file" >
 <input type="submit"  value="upload" >    
 <h3><u>Results</u></h3> 
 <img src="{{url_for('static',filename = image)}}" align="middle" style="width:150px"/>
 <p>{{data}}</p>
 <p>{{data3}}</p>
 </form>
```

Comment: is the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` also the static folder?

Comment: Yes. Its in the static folder. `UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static'
`

Comment: so the local path in host is `os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)`. try `path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)` and `print(path)` and `print(os.path.isfile(path))`, to see if the file has been actually saved. And, what does your func `prepare` do?

Comment: I have edited the question. Function prepare is used for that image preprocessing. ```def prepare(file): IMG_SIZE = 100 img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) img_array = img_array/255.0 new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) sample_array = new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) return sample_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good idea to specify a relative path to `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` since the current directory is not a reliable value. You could use a path relative to the python script though. like this:

```
app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app_dir, 'static')
```

Now the path in app.config will always be the static folder beside the script file.

then do your stuff:

```
file = request.files['file']
if file:
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

    # task 1. let's get a clear path
    path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    # task 2. make sure the folder exists
    folder = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        raise IOError('no such folder: %s' % folder)

    file.save(path)

    # ... then do template rendering...
    return render_template(...)
```

btw. using `file` as a variable name is a bad idea. the `file` is a builtin type in python.

Comment: Its showing the same problem. The images are getting stored in 'static' folder but its not displaying the image after we click submit button.

Comment: @SijinJohn right click the page to view the source html, get the src path of `<img>` tag. add the host prefix to it and put it to your browser, eg. `http://localhost:8080/static/abc.png`. see what happens. `404` or something else?

Comment: @SijinJohn you maybe already know, but, some kinds of images won't display correctly in web page. like CYMK mode jpg, etc. We wipe out all possible causes then we get the answer.

Comment: But its working for single module (eg: for body_segmentation). Not working if we add 3 to 4 modules. And itz giving error _This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED_

Comment: @SijinJohn it's a flask wsgi application, right? adding modules means? python module or  flask blueprint? would you provider some of your app setup code, lines around `app = Flask(...)`?

Comment: The images are stored in _static_ folder...but its not taking the image in _return render_template('bs1.html',**image=uploadimage**, data=data2, data3=data3)_

Comment: @SijinJohn does it work fine now? here is my thought if not. Try open your page in chrome or firefox, to check the network tab of the devtools window, to see if the image request waits for too long after it was sent. If so, consider run your wsgi app in a production server like unicorn, uwsgi etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you render the template for 'bs.html', you pass in the image file name; Should that be the file path instead, i.e. abc?

Comment: Tried...but its not showing the image when we click submit button.I have edited my question.